# Gomory-Chvátal Cut and Closure

Tags: optimization, definition, linear-programming, integer-programming

We're having the following definitions and example in our lecture.

[image]
[image]

I'm getting a bit confused. What is the first Chvátal closure of $P$ in this picture (please be specific)? Why is it not necessarily the integer polyhedron $P_I$, even though we've taken all possible values of $y$?

(Please skip to edit 2)

=====
**Edit:** using the multiplier $y^T = [\frac{7}{34} \ \frac{2}{34}]$, I manage to get the GC cut $-x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 7$, which is similar, but not quite, the red segment joining $(2,4)$ and $(4,5)$, i.e. $-x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 6$. Have I missed a step, or does that line segment simply cannot be derived as a GC cut from the original inequalities $(1),(2)$ (and hence not part of the first closure)?

I'm having trouble understand the definition because, while it is a clear specification, there can potentially be many values of $y$ that qualify, so I can't picture which GC cuts can be generated for the first closure and which cannot.

=====
**Edit 2:** I've managed to decode the slide a bit more. There's one typo at the line $-6x_1 + 8x_2 \leq 10$. It should be $-6x_1 + 8x_2 \leq 20$.

Also please disregard the multiplier I found in edit 1. It's wrong, as pointed out by Siong Thye Goh below. (Thanks)

Regardless, I try to follow the procedure and find multipliers, and realize to get to (7) it's a two-step process:

- First apply the multiplier $[\frac{1}{2} \ 0]$ to $\begin{bmatrix} -6 & 8 \\ 2 & 3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 21 \\ 27 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ to get (5): $-3x_1 + 4x_2 \leq \lfloor 10.5 \rfloor = 10$.
- Add this new inequality to the original two, and use the multiplier $[0 \ 3 \ 2]$ on the new system, i.e. on $\begin{bmatrix} -6 & 8 \\ 2 & 3 \\ -3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 21 \\ 27 \\ 10 \end{bmatrix}$, to get (7): $x_2 \leq \lfloor \frac{101}{17} \rfloor = 5$. (Technically the third lines of the matrices can replace the first ones, as the example seems to have done, but I want to follow the procedure and not using shortcuts that can muddle it. Anyway the multiplier $0$ makes sure that the redundant inequality will be crossed out).

This analysis makes it clear what happens in the example, but it still doesn't answer my questions about which specific inequalities make up the first Chvátal closure and how I know that I've got there, since there are so many multipliers that could qualify. The only insight/conjecture I got is that (7) does not belong to the first closure, since it cannot be derived directly from the first two inequalities. But I'm not sure about this conclusion.

Comment: Although the definition given is the formal definition, it is too general. If we want to do the Gomory cutting planes procedure manually, we usually do like your given example instead of finding the "multipliers".

Comment: Can you please address the subquestions I have in the post? The most essential for me is to understand how to visualize the closures, and how to go from one to the next.

Comment: So far there has been no answers to those and I'm stuck without a way to go forward, since many of the latter material contains analysis on the closures.

Comment: BTW, there are some typos in the figure. I believe that the purple (5) cut should be a purple (6), and the red (6) cut should be a red (7)

Comment: Here are the subquestions that I have: 1. Which inequalities define the first closure (please be specific)? 2. If I can't rely on the definition to characterize the closures, how do I know when I'm at the first closure, second closure, etc.? 3. Is there a systematic way to go from one closure to the next? The computations in the example, while correct, seem a bit random to me and doesn't illustrate the idea in the definitions.

Comment: Sorry that I wrote a bunch of things but realized that your question is to directly cut the polyhedron instead of solving a linear programming. Basically, the inequalities (1)(2)(3)(4)(5) is the first closure. The first closure usually comes from finding the common factors in $A$, and all the following procedure is from the linear combinations of the new inequalities.

Comment: Thanks. In the second edit I noted that (7) cannot be derived directly from (1)(2)(3)(4) so it does not belong to the first closure (and likely belong to the second closure). Is this observation correct? Another thing is that after we've got (5), how do we know that we've exhausted all inequalities constituting the first closure? I mean sure (5) would lead to (7), but how do I know nothing else could be constructed from (1)(2)(3)(4)?

Comment: There is this lemma that follows: if $F$ is a face of $P$, then $F' = P' \cap F$. In the picture, I'm focusing on the face $F$ of $P$ defined by (1)(2)(4). If $P'$ is defined by (1)(2)(3)(4)(5), then actually we just need (2)(3)(4)(5). But then wouldn't $P' \cap F = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine if your choice of $y$ satisfies the condition stated:

$y \ge 0$ but $y^TA=(-\frac{38}{34}, \frac{62}{34}) \notin \mathbb{Z}^2$, hence the $y$ does not satisfies the condition.

---

$$-6y_1 + 2y_2=k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$8y_1+3y_2=k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Then we have $$\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}=\frac1{-18-16}\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 \\ -8 & -6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2\end{bmatrix}=-\frac1{34}\begin{bmatrix} 3k_1-2k_2 \\ -8k_1-6k_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

We want $$34y_1=-3k_1 +2k_2 \ge 0\tag{1}$$

and $$34y_2=8k_1+6k_2 \ge 0\tag{2}$$

Multiply $(1)$ by $8$ and add to $3$ times of $(2)$ show that $k_2 \ge 0$.

$$\frac{-3}{4}k_2 \le k_1 \le  \frac{2}{3}k_2$$

We want to find $x_1, x_2$ such that for all $k_2 \ge 0, \frac{-3}{4}k_2 \le k_1 \le  \frac{2}{3}k_2 $, the following holds:

\begin{align}k_1x_1+k_2x_2 &\le \lfloor21y_1+27y_2\rfloor \\&= \lfloor\frac{21(-3k_1+2k_2)+27(8k_1+6k_2)}{34}\rfloor \\&=\lfloor \frac{153k_1+204k_2}{34}\rfloor \\
&= \lfloor4.5k_1 +6k_2 \rfloor \\
&= 4.5k_1+6k_2 - 0.5\mathbb{1}_{k_1 \text{ is odd}}\end{align}

Notice that when $k_2=0$, then we must have $k_1=0$ and every $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies, hence it is not interesting.

We will assume that $k_2 >0$ from now on. Under this setting, we can rewrite the inequality as

$$\frac{k_1}{k_2}x_1 +x_2 \le \frac92 \frac{k_1}{k_2}+6 - \frac{\mathbb{1}_{k_1 \text{ is odd}}}{2k_2} \tag{3}$$

For simplicity, I will denote $m=\frac{k_1}{k_2}$ and we want $$-\frac34 \le m \le \frac23$$

Example of valid cut is when $k_1=-3, k_2=4$, we obtained the cut:

$$-3x_1+4x_2 \le 10$$

which can be rewritten as

$$-\frac34 x_1 + x_2 \le \frac52\tag{4}$$

Another valid cut is when $k_1=2, k_2=3$, we obtain the following cut:

$$2x_1+3x_2 \le 27$$

which can be rewritten as

$$\frac23 x_1 + x_2 \le 9\tag{5}$$

Let's consider the implication of $(4)$ and $(5)$.

Suppose $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and $m = \alpha \left( -\frac34\right)+(1-\alpha)\left( \frac23 \right) \iff \alpha = \frac8{17}-\frac{12}{17}m$, then $(4)$ and $(5)$ would imply that

\begin{align}mx_1 + x_2 &\le \frac52 \alpha + (1-\alpha)9\\&=9-\frac{13}2\alpha  \\
&=9 - \frac{13}2 \left(\frac{8}{17} - \frac{12}{17}m \right)\\
&= \frac{101}{17} + \frac{78}{17}m\end{align}

Compare with the inequality in $(3)$, we investigate when does

$$\frac{101}{17} + \frac{78}{17}m\ \le \frac92 m+6 - \frac{\mathbb{1}_{k_1 \text{ is odd}}}{2k_2}  $$

which can be simplifed to

$$\frac{101}{17} + \frac{78}{17}m\ \le \frac92 m+6 - \frac{\mathbb{1}_{k_1 \text{ is odd}}}{2k_2}  $$

$$\frac3{34}m \le \frac1{17}- \frac{\mathbb{1}_{k_1 \text{ is odd}}}{2k_2}$$

$$m \le \frac23- \frac{17\mathbb{1}_{k_1 \text{ is odd}}}{3k_2}$$

Hence when $k_1$ is even, the inequalities hold for sure. Hence we do not need to add any more cuts with $k_1$ being even. Any additional non-redundant cut must be due to $k_1$ being odd.

Let's explore a few values of $k_2$ and see the possible values of odd $k_1$'s from $-\frac34 k_2 \le k_1 \le \frac23 k_2$.

If $k_2=1$, there is no feasible $k_1$ odd value.

If $k_2=2$, then we have odd $k_1 \in \{-1,1\}$.

The corresponding cuts are

$$-\frac12 x_1 + x_2 \le \frac72 \tag{6}$$
$$\frac12 x_1 + x_2 \le 8 \tag{7}$$

An implication is $x_2 \le \frac{23}4$.

If $k_2=3$, $k_1 \in \{-1,1\}$, I claim that we do not need to include them explicitly into the set once we have the $4$ cuts that I stated earlier.  Furthermore, we do not need to include any more additional cuts.

We will consider $3$ cases:

- $m \in \left[ -\frac34, -\frac12\right]$, in this case, we write $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $m= -\frac34 \alpha - \frac12 (1-\alpha)=-\frac12 -\frac14\alpha \iff \alpha = -4m-2$. Now, from equation $(4)$ and equation $(6)$, we have \begin{align}mx_1 + x_2 &\le  \frac52 \alpha + \frac72 (1-\alpha) \\ &= \frac72 -\alpha \\
  &=\frac72 -(-4m-2)\\&= 4m +\frac{11}2\end{align}

Compare with the inequality in $(3)$, we investigate when does the following hold for sure:

$$4m +\frac{11}2 \le \frac92m + 6 - \frac{1}{2k_2}$$
$$-1 \le m  - \frac{1}{k_2}$$
$$\frac1{k_2} \le m+1 $$

which is true when $k_2 \ge 4$. For the cases when $k_2 < 4$, we have examine it manually.

---

- $m \in \left[ -\frac12, -\frac12\right]$, in this case, we write $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $m= -\frac12 \alpha + \frac12 (1-\alpha)=\frac12 -\alpha \iff \alpha = -m+\frac12$. Now, from equation $(6)$ and equation $(7)$, we have \begin{align}mx_1 + x_2 &\le  \frac72 \alpha + 8 (1-\alpha) \\ &= 8 -\frac92\alpha \\
  &=8 -\frac92(-m + \frac12)\\&= \frac{9m}2 +\frac{23}4\end{align}

Compare with the inequality in $(3)$, we investigate when does the following hold for sure:

$$\frac{9m}2 +\frac{23}4 \le \frac92m + 6 - \frac{1}{2k_2}$$
$$23 \le 24  - \frac{2}{k_2}$$
$$\frac2{k_2} \le 1 \iff k_2 \ge 2 $$

which is true when $k_2 \ge 2$ within this range. For the cases when $k_2 < 2$, we have examine it manually.

---

- $m \in \left[ \frac12, \frac23\right]$, in this case, we write $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $m= \frac12 \alpha + \frac23 (1-\alpha)=\frac23 -\frac16\alpha \iff \alpha = 4-6m$. Now, from equation $(7)$ and equation $(5)$, we have \begin{align}mx_1 + x_2 &\le  8 \alpha + 9 (1-\alpha) \\ &= 9 -\alpha \\
  &=9 -(4-6m )\\&= 5+6m\end{align}

Compare with the inequality in $(3)$, we investigate when does the following hold for sure:

$$5+6m \le \frac92m + 6 - \frac{1}{2k_2}$$
$$\frac32m \le 1  - \frac{1}{2k_2}$$
$$3k_1 \le 2k_2-1 $$

$$3k_1 + 1 \le 2k_2 $$

Recall that we know that $k_1$ is odd,

Hence it is equivalent to $$3k_1 \le 2k_2$$

which is just $$m \le \frac23$$

which is true for our condition. Hence, only $(4), (5), (6), (7)$ are needed.

[image]

Comment: You are right. I don't know why I got that $[\frac{7}{34} \frac{2}{34}]$ from. However, with different values of $y_1, y_2$, we get different values of $k_1, k_2$ and hence different set of $(x_1,x_2)$ satisfying the conditions of $P'$. If I just keep trying different values of $y_1, y_2$ (or $k_1, k_2$) and not look at the picture, how do I know when to stop and confirm that I have obtained $P'$? How do I know which inequalities are redundant?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you can specify in the picture in the question, which inequalities define $P'$, and if it's not the same as $P^{(o)}$, which inequalities we cannot generate before coming to the first closure.

Comment: For this particular question, I have some conjectures but it's a busy day today. Might revisit it later.

Comment: remark: 2 cuts are not suffices, at least $4$ cuts, work in progress.

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh, I am working on implementing the CG cuts on the 3-dimensional polyhedron. I would like to use the approach you mentioned to derive the cuts, but I have some issues. Would you say please, what you described in the first lines seem to be dual of the original polytope. (1) Is it a general approach? I mean can I use it to apply in my case?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh, (2)  how we can show $\frac{-3}{4}k_2 \le k_1 \le  \frac{2}{3}k_2$ based on the inequalities $1$ and $2$? (3) what does `Notice that when $k_2=0$, then we must have $k_1=0$ and every $x \in R^2$ satisfies, hence it is not interesting` mean? how we can obtain $-\frac34 \le m \le \frac23$?