# For a polyhedron $P$ associated with an LP, find a polyhedral description of the integer polyhedron $P_{IP}$ using Gomory-Chvátal cuts.

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra, integer-programming

> Consider the polyhedron $P=\left\{\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}: x_{1}+4 x_{2} \leq 8, x_{1}+x_{2} \leq 4\right\} .$ Find a
>   polyhedral description of $P_{I P}$ using GC-cuts. What is the Chvátal-rank of $P_{I}$ (w.r.t. $P) ?$

I've found several valid cuts for this problem, such as $x_1+2x_2 \leq 5$, using some random GC multipliers. But I don't know how to approach this task in a systematic way.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is two dimensions, a good place to start is to plot the feasible region, enumerate the integer feasible solutions, and determine which of these define the integer hull.  Then you can see which cuts are needed.

Comment: I've done that and see the convex hull of the final integer polyhedron should be defined by $x_1,x_2 \geq 0$, $x_1 + x_2 \leq 4$  and $x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 6$, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Correct so far.  You already have $x_1+x_2 \le 4$.  So now you need some dual multipliers to derive $x_1+3x_2 \le 6$ from the given constraints.

Comment: That should be $[2 \ 1]$ isn't it? Then I can sum up the two resulting inequalities, dividing the result by $3$. That should give the needed inequality, but I don't know how to show that I'm done. Also, regarding the question about rank, I'm still confused about the concept of closure.

Comment: If possible please have a look at an earlier question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693796/gomory-chv%c3%a1tal-cut-and-closure

Comment: Yes, $2/3$ and $1/3$ suffice, and because you did it from the original constraints (and not any derived constraints), the rank is $1$.